# PSTricks: Draw arrows along path

Tags: pstricks

Inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187697/how-to-decorate-a-parametric-function-drawn-with-datavisualization), I've tried to find a command for drawing arrows along a path with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.5,1.5)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1.2,-1.2)(1.3,1.3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \parametricplot[
    linecolor = red,
    linewidth = 1.2pt,
    plotstyle = ccurve
  ]{0}{180}{
    3 t mul cos t cos mul
    3 t mul cos t sin mul
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Is it possible to draw arrows along anything but lines (see page 96--97 in the [`pstricks-add` manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pstricks-add/doc/pstricks-add-doc.pdf))? In case it is, how do I do that?

**Update**

Herbert has given an alternative PSTricks solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188060/15874).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with the `\pscurvepoints` command, which creates an array of points on the curve, and `\pspolylineticks` (§ 30 of pstricks-add documentation: *Ticks and other marks along a curve, pp. 107–117).
What I don't understand quite well are the parameters, so I played with them. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[pdf, x11names]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 5}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.5,1.5)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1.2,-1.2)(1.3,1.3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \parametricplot[
    linecolor = red,
    linewidth = 1.2pt,
    plotstyle = ccurve,
    plotpoints=100
  ]{0}{180}{
    3 t mul cos t cos mul
    3 t mul cos t sin mul
  }
\pscurvepoints[plotpoints=100]{0}{180}{
    3 t mul cos t cos mul
    3 t mul cos t sin mul
  }{P}
%
\pspolylineticks[Os=0,Ds=1,ticksize=0 0]{P}%
{ ds }{0}{360}% distance
\multido{\i=0+1}{100}{\psrline[linecolor = red,linewidth = 1.2pt, arrows=->,arrowscale=2](PTick\i)(2pt;{(
PTangent\i)})}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

And the resulting curve:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now I just have to find out how to control the number of arrows. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Not really. Seems to be a matter of ratio between the number of plot points and the value of Ds.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.5,1.5)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1.2,-1.2)(1.3,1.3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \parametricplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.2pt,plotpoints=100]%
    {0}{Pi}
    { cos(3*t)*cos(t) | cos(3*t)*sin(t) }
  \multido{\rT=0.3+0.5}{12}{%
      \parametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=2,linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.2pt,
                      arrows=->,arrowscale=1.5]%
        {\rT}{\rT\space 0.01 add}%
        { cos(3*t)*cos(t) | cos(3*t)*sin(t) }}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The arrow is drawn with the same function and a very short line segment of only 2 points. It starts with `x=cos(3*0.3)*cos(0.3)` and `y=cos(3*0.3)*sin(0.3)`. With 6 steps you have one "round" of the curve: `6*0.5=3` which is nearly Pi