# Drawing ticks/arrows along a Bezier curve in PStricks

Tags: pstricks, arrows, bezier

Along the lines of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187707/pstricks-draw-arrows-along-path), I would like to know if there is a way to automate tick drawing along a curve generated by `psbezier` in PSTricks (and potentially `pspolygon` and more complex curves encapsulated in `pscustom`). What I would like to achieve is something like this:

[image: line with arrows]

where the curve has been generated by `psbezier`. (Here, the arrows have been drawn, placed and oriented manually to fit the shape of the curve — very time-consuming.)

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,4)
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{0}{9}{t^2/9 | sin(t)+1}%
\pscurvepoints{0}{9}{(t^2)/9 | sin(t)+1}{P}%
% make ticks using arc-length metric
\pspolylineticks[metricInitValue=1,ticksize=-2pt 2pt,Os=1,Ds=.2]{P}{ ds }{1}{56}%
\pspolylineticks[metricInitValue=1,Os=1,Ds=2]{P}{ ds }{0}{6}%
\multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=3+2}{5}{\Put{6pt;(PNormal\iA)}(PTick\iA){\tiny \iB}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(5,3) \psset{arrowscale=1.5}
\psbezier[ArrowInsideNo=9,ArrowInside=->]{*->}(0,0)(1,3)(3,0)(5,3)
\end{pspicture}

\psset{unit=0.75cm} 
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-5)(15,5)
\psbezier[ArrowInsideNo=19, ArrowInside=-|,  
    showpoints=true]{->}(-3,0)(5,-5)(8,5)(15,-5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]