# Add arrows on parametricplot

Tags: arrows, plot, line, pspicture, arrow-curve

Hi i'm trying to add the red arrows on the curves, I got arrows on the line with  ArrowInside, but on the parametricplot coundn't get it. 
[image]

```
\psset{arrowscale=2,ArrowFill=true}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(5,4)%\grilla
\psaxes[linewidth=1.1pt,labels=none,
ticks=none]{-}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.3pt}

\foreach \expr in {SINH(t)|COSH(t),COSH(t)|SINH(t),SINH(t)|-COSH(t),-COSH(t)|SINH(t)}
{\psparametricplot[linewidth=1.3pt,ArrowInside=->>,ArrowInsideNo=2]{-2}{2}{\expr}}

\psline[linewidth=1.3pt, linewidth=1.3pt,ArrowInside=->>, ArrowInsideNo=2,ArrowInsideOffset=0.1](-4,-4)(0,0)
\psline[linewidth=1.3pt, linewidth=1.3pt,ArrowInside=->>, ArrowInsideNo=2,ArrowInsideOffset=0.1](4,4)(0,0)
\psline[linewidth=1.3pt, linewidth=1.3pt,ArrowInside=->>, ArrowInsideNo=2,ArrowInsideOffset=0.1](0,0)(4,-4)
\psline[linewidth=1.3pt, linewidth=1.3pt,ArrowInside=->>, ArrowInsideNo=2,ArrowInsideOffset=0.1](0,0)(-4,4)

\end{pspicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same approach as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187707/pstricks-draw-arrows-along-path/188149#188149): redraw using `multido`. In order to let the arrows point to the directions as desired, change `SINH(t)|COSH(t)` to `-SINH(t)|COSH(t)` and `COSH(t)|SINH(t)` to `COSH(t)|-SINH(t)`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\psset{arrowscale=2,ArrowFill=true}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%\grilla
\psaxes[linewidth=1.1pt,labels=none,
ticks=none]{-}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.3pt}

\foreach \expr in {-SINH(t)|COSH(t),COSH(t)|-SINH(t),SINH(t)|-COSH(t),-COSH(t)|SINH(t)}{
 \psparametricplot[linewidth=1.3pt]{-2}{2}{\expr}
 \multido{\n=-1+0.8}{4}{%
  \parametricplot[plotpoints=2,linecolor=red,linewidth=0.1pt,arrows=->,arrowscale=5]{\n}{\n\space 0.01 add}{\expr}
 }
}

\psline[linewidth=1.3pt, linewidth=1.3pt,ArrowInside=->>, ArrowInsideNo=2,ArrowInsideOffset=0.1](-4,-4)(0,0)
\psline[linewidth=1.3pt, linewidth=1.3pt,ArrowInside=->>, ArrowInsideNo=2,ArrowInsideOffset=0.1](4,4)(0,0)
\psline[linewidth=1.3pt, linewidth=1.3pt,ArrowInside=->>, ArrowInsideNo=2,ArrowInsideOffset=0.1](0,0)(4,-4)
\psline[linewidth=1.3pt, linewidth=1.3pt,ArrowInside=->>, ArrowInsideNo=2,ArrowInsideOffset=0.1](0,0)(-4,4)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

You may want to change `\n=-1+0.8` to something else in order to shift the arrows to another position.